# WiX v4 custom actions not working after migration

Tags: wix

I'm have 2 msi's containing custom actions (which worked in wix v3) - these will run packaged exes.

```
    <Fragment>
<CustomAction Id="RunExecutable"
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" 
              ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]my.exe" 
              Execute="deferred" 
              Impersonate="no" 
              Return="asyncNoWait" />

<CustomAction Id="RunIt" 
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" 
              ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]run_it.cmd" 
              Execute="deferred" 
              Impersonate="no" 
              Return="asyncNoWait" />
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="RunExecutable" After="InstallFiles"/>
        <Custom Action="RunIt" After="RunExecutable"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
</Fragment>
```

**WHAT IVE TRIED**
I have mainly tried different inputs for attributes such as 'execute' e.g commit and immediate. Additionally, I've tried to make  the execommand the true path to the exe e.g
execommand=c:\wix\run_it.cmd.

sadly alot of documentation is focused around custom actions which require binary/dll reference but last I checked exes don't require this.

As i said this worked perfectly in v3, but im assuming something has changed in v4 - any help is appreciated.